# Is there a CLI-only package to convert MS Office files to PDF?

Tags: command-line, pdf, microsoft-office, conversion, libreoffice

Is there a command-line interface *only* package to convert Microsoft Office files to PDF?
Specifically, I need to be able to export

- `doc`/`docx` (Word),
- `ppt`/`pptx` (PowerPoint),
- `xls`/`xlsx` (Excel), and
- `vsd`/`vsdx` (Visio).

I am aware that an installation of [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) comes with a CLI to convert documents,
  but [it does not appear to support Visio diagrams](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/11692/commandline-document-conversion-with-libreoffice).
Is there a package that does?

---

Ideally I'd like a solution that works on Linux,
  but I could find a way to use Windows if it would be far more practical.
What I will very likely not have is a license to any MS products.

Comment: what version of office?

Comment: @Keltari I'm not sure.  I don't think I will be working with *anything* pre-2003, but I think 2007 is a safe baseline.

Comment: I dont have an office 2007 app to see, but check to see if you can save as PDF from the Save As.  If so, then you can write a VBScript to convert to PDF.  I know this can be done for 2010 and up.

Comment: @Keltari I believe every version from 2003 on supports export as PDF. 2007 confirmed. Note though that I do not have a version of Office available, as I mentioned in the bit @-terdon edited out...

Comment: Since [4.0, LO has a Visio import filter](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/4-0-new-features-and-fixes#Filters). I never used it myself, so i can't tell how "powerful" it is, but it may be worth a try.

Comment: @SeanAllred PDF export was introduced originally as a downloadable add-in for 2007, then later incorporated as a built-in feature of 2007 in the first service pack; later versions have PDF export built in.  2003 and earlier did not have any PDF export other than what was added by Adobe Acrobat or other products.

Comment: For macOS, you can use my docx2pdf tool: https://github.com/AlJohri/docx2pdf. If you're on windows, it's fairly easy to extend this approach for other Office tools using the win32com interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can use powershell. You can write your own, but often MS already has such scripts written for you, because all recent office supports powershell and thus can be operated on by powershell scripts. Here are some examples, and you can find more in technet.

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Script-to-convert-Word-f702844d

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/09/06/save-a-microsoft-excel-workbook-as-a-pdf-file-by-using-powershell.aspx

first, you probably can read this:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742371.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use `docto` its a really simple command line utility that allows you to convert Word Documents to pdf or any other format.

https://github.com/tobya/DocTo

as simple as

```
docto -f C:\Directory\MyFile.doc -O "C:\Output Directory\MyTextFile.pdf" -T wdFormatPDF
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up a PDF printer and make it default, then

```
Winword.exe  some.doc /q /n /mFilePrintDefault /mFileExit
```

Comment: Per the original question, I do not have a license for (therefore no copies of) any Microsoft Office products.  `winword.exe` is *definitely* a Microsoft Office product.

Comment: just saw the case, bare in mind that you probably will suffer formatting lost in most case for any method other than using a actual MS word to print to "PDF", even if print with a MS word viewer suffer formatting lost.

Comment: I realize that, and it's something we took under consideration before embarking on this.

Comment: alternatively, you can simply unzip it, then grep the document.xml, and use sed to get all the text between <w:t> and </w:t>

Comment: that's how we read a docx in unix.

Comment: While formatting is not a *major* concern, there needs to be *some* formatting.  We've also considered Pandoc for this purpose, but feel it is best to keep as close to the original formatting as possible.

Answer (score -1):

You may use VeryDOC DOC to Any Converter Command Line software, that software does convert office files to PDF file in command line.

such as,

doc2any.exe D:\test.doc D:\out.pdf
doc2any.exe D:\test.docx D:\out.pdf
doc2any.exe D:\test.xls D:\out.pdf
doc2any.exe D:\test.ppt D:\out.pdf

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but it would probably help to link to the software and mention what it's license is.

Comment: The software is not free btw

Comment: It appears that doc2any requires a resident copy of Office.